# ¿textarea con la letra ñ me funcione con html y php?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

lo que intento es que una persona escriba un mensaje en un textarea y con php imprimirlo una letra más adelantado (la a pasa a ser b, la b a c...) en la pantalla. El código es así (solo funciona para las letras h, o, l y a, pero eso es simplemente para el ejemplo. lo único que me interesa es que la ñ al meterla con el texarea no me la detecta en en switch y me lo pone en el default):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$texto=$_POST["text"];
$abcd = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
$texto2=str_split($texto);
for ($i=0; $i <count($texto2); $i++) {
    switch ($texto2[$i]) {
        case 'h':
            echo $abcd[7];
            break;
        case 'o':
             echo $abcd[15];
            break;
        case 'l':
             echo $abcd[11];
            break;
        case 'a':
             echo $abcd[0];
            break;
        case 'ñ':
             echo $abcd[14];
            break;
        default:
             echo $abcd[1];
            break;
    };
}
?>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8" /></head>
<body>
    <form action="prueba.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar la siguiente solución

```
 $test = "Nuñez";
    echo utf8_decode($test);
```

Aqui esta tu codigo con la modificación implementada.

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$texto=$_POST["text"];
$abcd = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
$texto2=str_split(utf8_decode($texto));
for ($i=0; $i <count($texto2); $i++) {
    switch ($texto2[$i]) {
        case 'h':
            echo $abcd[7];
            break;
        case 'o':
             echo $abcd[15];
            break;
        case 'l':
             echo $abcd[11];
            break;
        case 'a':
             echo $abcd[0];
            break;
        case utf8_decode('ñ'):
             echo $abcd[14];
            break;
        default:
             echo $abcd[1];
            break;
    };
}
?>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8" /></head>
<body>
    <form action="prueba.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y hay que poner el utf8_decode también en el srt_slipt y funciona muchas gracias. ` $texto2=str_split(utf8_decode($texto));`

Comment: Excelente, ya implemente la modificación para que pueda ayudar a otras personas también.